# How to remove CR in error message in sftp stderr

Tags: linux, gmail, sftp

I am using Linux 2.6.32-573.26.1

I use a_script to run batch sftp to get file from another Linux server

Here is the way to run a_script

```
a_script > a_script.log.wri 2>&1
```

Here is a_script:

```
echo script start at `date`
sftp -b myCommandFile user@server 
echo script end at `date`
```

Inside myCommandFile, there are these commands:

```
lls an_non_exist_file
```

Because cannot find an_non_exist_file
The error message is:

```
ls: cannot access an_non_exist_file: No such file or directory  
Shell exited with status 2^M
```

So, a_script.log.wri will contain everything, including the line

```
Shell exited with status 2^M
```

It is this line to spoil everything.

Because there is a Carriage-return ^M char in the a_script.log.wri
, when I attached this file into a email and send to gmail
, the gmail cannot open it.

Although it is a file with extension wri
, the gamil just does not open it.

I am using Nexus 5x to read the email inside gmail.
The Android does not open the attachment file a_script.log.wri

I try to create a file dummy.wri inside Linux with 5 lines and only the 3rd line having a ending carriage-return char.  Other 4 lines are ended with LF.

Then, I attach this dummy.wri file in a email and sent to the gmail account.

Well, really it cannot open dummy.wri

If there is no ending carriage-return, everything is fine.  I can open it inside the gmail inside Android of Nexus 5x.

So, my question is , how to make sftp NOT to add the carriage-return char when displaying the error message ?

Also, instead of using lls, using ls an_non_exist_file will get similar situation.

Alvin SIU

Comment: Have you tried `a_script  2>&1 | sed 's/\r$//' > a_script.log.wri` ?

Comment: Yes, I use similar method as a workaround.  My question is: since everything is running in unix environment, why the sftp like to use CRLF as line delimiter ? Also, there seems to be no way to tell sftp to use LF as line delimiter.